# Travel to UK with USA criminal record

Tags: visas, uk, applications, study, criminal-records

I am a citizen of Bangladesh.  I was residing in USA and was arrested back in 2012 for evading arrest with vehicle.  Later I was convicted and I went to prison for 2 years due to ineffective assistance of counsel.  After I served my sentence I was deported back to Bangladesh in August 2019.  So I'm now trying to go the UK for study.

My question is do I need to tell the UK embassy about my criminal story? If I don't tell the embassy, will they be able to find about my criminal history?  Please advise me.

Comment: You most definitely need to tell. They will ask.

Comment: You must tell them about both the criminal record and the deportation. There are specific questions on the application form - do not be tempted to lie.

Answer (score 8):

The US shares criminal records with several other countries, including the UK. UK border officers will be able to access your US criminal history.

You should disclose the criminal conviction on your visa application. Doing so does not automatically mean you will be refused; that depends on [the specific crime and how much time has passed since you served your sentence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/85319/3221). (Though, based on the details you have provided, I would expect that not enough time has passed for you to be able to get past this hurdle.) However, if you do not disclose the conviction, the UK will consider this deception and you are likely to receive a 10 year ban from entering the UK.

Comment: And at that point, with a prison record from one country and a ten-year ban from another, you may find it very hard to get a visa for *anywhere*.  Don't do this to yourself!